# Probability that two specific elements are in uniformly random sample

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, sampling, streaming-algorithm

Consider the sampling algorithm as described [here](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/%7Egraham/ssbd/ssbd2.pdf) section 2.2 specifically Algorithm 2.4.

Essentially we are given a stream of $N$ elements and wish to maintain a uniformly random sample, $S$, of size $k$. Initially we put $k$ elements into $S$ and then for each iteration, $i \in [k+1, N]$ we choose a random number $x \in [1,i]$ and if $x \leq k$ we replace the $x$'th element from $S$ with the element seen at iteration $i$.

I see answers online e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87631/reservoir-sampling-algorithm-probability) that after iteration $N$ each element from the stream has probability $k/N$ to be in the sample $S$. However what is the probability that two elements $x_l$ and $x_j$ where $l \neq j$ are both in the sample after iteration $N$? As i understand it the event that $x_l$ is sampled is not independent from the event that $x_j$ is sampled since we would have fewer slots to choose from when including $x_j$ assuming it occurs later than $x_l$ in the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us study the event that $x_a$ and $x_b$ are both in the reservoir at the end of the algorithm, where $k < a < b$.

In order for this to occur four things must happen:

1. On the $a$th iteration the random number must be $\leq k$.
2. Between the $a$th and $b$th iteration $x_a$ must not be replaced.
3. On the $b$th iteration the random number generator must be $\leq k$ but also not equal the location of $x_a$. WLOG we say that the random number must be $\leq k-1$.
4. For the remaining iterations neither $x_a$ or $x_b$ must be replaced.

This gives us the equation

$$p = \frac{k}{a} \cdot \prod_{i=a+1}^{b-1}(1 - 1/i)\cdot \frac{k-1}{b}\cdot \prod_{i=b+1}^n(1-2/i).$$

Left as an exercise to the reader, this solves to
$$p = \frac{k}{a} \cdot \frac{a}{b-1}\cdot \frac{k-1}{b}\cdot \frac{(b-1)b}{(n-1)n},$$
$$p = \frac{(k-1)k}{(n-1)n}.$$

Thus the probability that $x_a, x_b$ are both in the sample is independent of $a, b$ when $k < a < b$. The case where $k \geq a$ is once again left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, we can show that at any given time, the current sample is a random sample of $k$ elements out of all elements seen so far. The proof is by induction on $n$, the number of elements seen so far. The base case $n = k$ is clear.

Now suppose that we know the claim for $n$. Thus after seeing $n$ elements, we have a random sample $S$ of $k$ elements out of these $n$ elements. Now we are seeing a new element $x$. With probability $k/(n+1)$, we remove a random element from $S$ and replace it with $x$.

The probability that the chosen sample is a specific subset of $k$ elements out of the first $n$ elements is thus
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}} \cdot \frac{n+1-k}{n+1} = \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{k}}.
$$
Now suppose $T$ is a subset of $k$ elements out of the first $n+1$ elements which contains the new element $x$. There are $n-(k-1)$ choices for $S$, resulting from adding an element $y$ to $T - x$. The probability that $x$ replaced $y$ rather than some other element is $1/(n+1)$, and altogether the probability that $T$ is the chosen sample is
$$
\frac{n-k+1}{\binom{n}{k}} \cdot \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{k}}.
$$
(In fact, this calculation must come out to be $1/\binom{n+1}{k}$, since all sets $T$ are equiprobable; but it is still instructive to see it.)